# Building a GPS Tracking Web System

Tags: gps, system, tracking

I'd like to develop a tracking system using an API of course (like [the famous Orange API](http://www.orangepartner.com/site/enuk/access_orange_apis/advanced_apis/sms_internet_api/p_sms_internet_api.jsp)).
the idea is simple:

- I send a SMS (from my Web interface) to the person i want to track
- The person's mobile terminal (GPS like [this](http://www.trackingtheworld.com/wtsms.htm)) send me back automatically
  the coordinates by SMS.
- The sent information are displayed on the user's web interface.

The questions are simple:

- How the terminal can send automatically the response?
- How to indicate in the message that the information is for "user4655"?
- How to make connection between the information and the database?

Thanks,

Regards.

Comment: This question seems to be making a lot of assumptions. What is the 'terminal'? A specific device? An abitrary cell phone? I don't see how this can be answered as is.

Answer (score 1):

```
* How the terminal can send automatically the response?
```

Ans: You set the gateway and the time intervals you want the device to send the sms to on the device itself.

```
* How to indicate in the message that the information is for "user4655"?
```

Ans: The gateway you use will have the API to determine that the number it is sent from. The device will use a registered phone number from either a sim or enabled by one of those cell providers.

```
* How to make connection between the information and the database?
```

Ans: I dont understand this. But I'm guessing you will have a database to keep track of the user data. You'll just probably need another table that is a child of the user, which has a list of the data and the time they came in.